# Powershell Topshelf Uninstall continues to lock files

Tags: c#, powershell, deployment, octopus-deploy, topshelf

Using the following topshelf uninstall command:

```
& $path uninstall -servicename:"MyService" -displayname "MyService"
```

The command seems to continue running for what seems like the lifetime of the powershell script it is contained in and lock the files so I cant overwrite them. Is there a way to ensure whatever its doing is terminated so my scripts can carry on unhindered?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to uninstall windows service. Could use as a [script module](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts/script-modules).

```
function Uninstall-WindowsService($serviceName)
{
    $existingService = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -filter "name='$serviceName'")
    if ($existingService) 
    {
      Write-Host "Stopping the '$serviceName'."
      Stop-Service $serviceName
      Write-Host "Waiting 3 seconds to allow existing service to stop."
      Start-Sleep -s 3

      $existingService.Delete()
      Write-Host "Waiting 15 seconds to allow service to be uninstalled."
      Start-Sleep -s 15
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    $servicePath = (Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -like $serviceName} | Select-Object Name, @{Name="Path"; Expression={$_.PathName.split('"')[1]}}).Path
    Write-Host "Uninstalling service from $servicePath"
    Invoke-Expression "$servicePath uninstall"}
```